# Git diff between current modification and another ref

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I would like to display the diff between my current work (in a dirty state) and another branch.

I can do:

```
$ git diff my_other_branch
```

Unfortunately the diff is reversed: I would like to exchange the ref (like `git diff a..b` => `git diff b..a`.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to deal with this, but the simplest is to use the `-R` (reverse the diff orientation) option to `git diff`.